# Multiple products (shopping cart) stripe API

Tags: php, stripe-payments, shopping-cart

I'd like to be able to itemize multiple products when charging with the stripe API. That way the automatically sent out receipt will list out each product. I don't want to just charge the total shopping cart amount and a general description.

How would I also add a $5 tie with the description 'tie' to the charge below.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1100,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'receipt_email' => $email,
    "description" => 'shirt'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not something that Stripe supports today. When you create a one-time charge via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), you can only pass the total amount to charge.

Another option would be to use the Orders [API](https://stripe.com/docs/orders). This lets you define Products in your account and then create an [Order](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order) that lists all the products being bought. The limitation though is that email receipts still won't display the list of items and you would have to use a [third-party application](https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/email-marketing-dunning).

Answer (score 0):

i prepare my cart collection as

```html
<?php 

$purchased='';


for($i=0;$i<count($POST['items']);$i++){

    $purchased.=( "=> item id : ".$POST['items'][$i]." unit price  ".$POST['price'][$i]." qnt ".$POST['qnt'][$i]." ;");
}

?>
```

then pass it to stripe description

```html
<?php 


$charge=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount"=>$total_fee*100,
    "currency"=>"usd",
    "description"=>$purchased,// the trick
    "customer"=>$customer->id
));
?>
```

this work fine for me but we need more